# Replace null with ID from right table in join

Tags: sql

I am doing a select with right join. And I have some rows with IDS from table A but not all rows have corresponding IDs in Table B.
I wish to replace null IDS from table B with IDS of table A based on other row.
That alternative row has no null values. How can it be done?

[image: Results sample/results desired]

Comment: Can you share your (faulty) query?

Comment: If the `id`s in `B` are `NULL`, how do you match them to `A`?

Comment: when I do my select in table A i have 10 rows return. In those 10 rows only 3 rows have corresponding in table B. All 7 rows they have null on Table b.ID. But i have another row that is in Table A only having values for all 10 rows. what to do so that i can have the IDs from table B where in table A is null for seven rows remaining

Comment: For Mureinik ----- My query is  select * from factureitem i left join Inscription iD -- on ip.Idinscription =i.IDinscription where Idfacture=7721

Comment: @Mureinik ... My query is select * from factureitem i left join Inscription iD -- on ip.Idinscription =i.IDinscription where Idfacture=7721

Answer (score 0):

SQL has a command for that...

```
ISNULL(TableB.Id, TableA.Id) AS SomeId
```

In the event of `TableB.Id` being `NULL`, you'll get `TableA.Id` as `SomeId`.

Comment: here are my results

Comment: It doesnot work your proposal. Can you check on my results of left join in order to have an idea of what i m facing as challenge. But the problem, I can not paste results in good order they look like html text instead of tables with rows and column.

Comment: when I do my select in table A i have 10 rows return. In those 10 rows only 3 rows have corresponding in table B. All 7 rows they have null on Table b.ID. But i have another row that is in Table A only having values for all 10 rows. what to do so that i can have the IDs from table B where in table A is null for seven rows remaining

Comment: Any one to help, still waiting for the answer please

Answer (score 0):

THIS ADDRESSES THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

First, I strongly recommend `left join` over `right join`.  It is easier to read a query when the logic is "keep all the rows in the first table (and I know what that is)".

You can use `coalesce()`.  In a `select` query, you would do:

```
select coalesce(b.id, a.id)
from a left join
     b
     on a.anothercol = b.anothercol;
```

However, I suspect you intend:

```
update b
    set id = (select a.id from a where a.anothercol = b.anothercol)
    where id is null;
```

Comment: here is my query with left join  
select
*

from finances.Factureitem i
-- (TAble A: IDfacture that cannot find --IDinscription in Table B)
left join  Inscriptions.Inscription ip --(Table B)
on ip.Idinscription =i.IDinscription
where Idfacture=7721

Comment: select coalesce(b.id, a.id)
from a left join
     b
     on a.anothercol = b.anothercol; the problem here another column is only in table A..... What can i do in such case?

Comment: @Blessed . . . You should edit your question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: How can i put line break please?

Comment: Please Gordon Linoff ...I added image in my question as results sample and desired. could you see it please let me know. Thank you. Here is the link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/37b2Y.jpg

Comment: did you see my results please? I still need your help. Thank you